# Jssor: Auto height with content slider

Tags: jquery, html, image, slideshow

I am using this plugin [Jssor](http://www.jssor.com/index.html) and i use this template [Full Width](http://www.jssor.com/demos/full-width-slider.html)
But this handle only the images with fixed height what about if i want to display images with full width and with auto height.

i checked this [link](https://github.com/jssor/slider.js/issues/2) talk about this issue but it didn't work for me amy be i didn't apply it right !!!

Could anyone help me in that issue

Thanks

Comment: please send me your work http://www.jssor.com/support.html

Comment: Great Slider but unfortunately I must to use another slider because of this weakness.